# Did Quickly die? How do I get it?

Tags: 16.04, quickly

Here's the (obscenely obsolete, as always) wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly

It tells me to `apt-get install quickly`. Okay:

```
$ sudo apt install quickly
...
E: Unable to locate package quickly
```

https://packages.ubuntu.com/quickly -- shows any signs of life in Trusty 14.04LTS only.
I'm on Xenial:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Didn't even tried the thing once. So sad!

Perhaps there's a PPA or something with newer builds?.. Anyone aware of any developments going on with Quickly?

Comment: If you feel that the wiki needs to be updated, then please join the Ubuntu Documentation Team (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DocumentationTeam) and help fix it rather than throwing stones.

Comment: @user535733 it's no stones. Most project wikis are like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
quickly 393 weeks ago
Successfully built
```

[Yes](https://launchpad.net/~quickly/+archive/ubuntu/daily-build), it's dead. You could try to build it from [source](https://launchpad.net/quickly/12.10/12.08.1/+download/quickly-12.08.1.tar.gz) using the latest version –
 see [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) –, but I really doubt the program is useful any more after such a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Quickly has indeed not been supported for quite some time, and no longer maintained.

Comment: Aahh, so sad when a tech dies before you even try it once.